# Where should I ask questions about using TI-84 calculators?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about why my TI-84 graphing calculator graphs things in a certain way. Specifically, it’s about why the TI-84 can’t display circles properly and there’s always a vertical gap.

It is not related to programming, and thus not for Stack Overflow, I think. It isn't really about math, so I don't think it seems on-topic for Math Stack Exchange. It's more about how computers work, but I don't believe TI-84s use any sort of version of another kind of OS (ruling out specific SE sites for operating systems), so I have no idea where it would be on-topic.

Where should I ask this?

**This is not about programming; it is about why the calculator works a certain way. It is not a duplicate.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: @gnat this is *specifically* about Ti-84 calculators; that's about programming and the like

Comment: @gnat i will concur with the asker here, as retrocomputing is a clear contender and yet is not listed at all on any part of that page at this time (other than the inconsequential comment i just added). (i guess if it were that easy to summarise then the [site-recommendation] tag would happily implode!). as it is, is there a chance of that linked answer becoming a complete maintained canon for the tech sites at least?

Comment: not really wanting to bump this again but note that my answer addresses the overall question as per your title, not just the one use case, and don't worry about using the word programming as the use case is about an inbuilt program within "a tool used primarily for programming", so the word 'programming' is still relevant without making this a dupe. christopher's answer is technically off topic but they are speaking from the heart so it's your call.

Answer (score 4):

Considering nobody with more experience has answered you here I'll venture forth..

There's two viable routes, [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/search?q=TI-84) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TI-84), which give 9 and 290 search results respectively (including questions and answers reffering the TI-84 model). I list RC first as I would personally consider it a safer option, but your mileage will vary.

Although the numbers suggest there is a larger acceptance for these devices in general on SO, consider further if your intent is to understand why a behaviour occurs from the device's use, or to produce or avoid specific behaviour when coding for the device.

Here are some crucial cues to help decide which destination is most appropriate, depending on your intentions.

**Retrocomputing**

> - How to use or preserve computing equipment that is no longer manufactured or supported by the manufacturer.
> - Hardware, including peripherals, and software, including operating systems and applications.
> - [Are questions about calculators on-topic?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/are-questions-about-calculators-on-topic)

**Stack Overflow**

> - A specific programming problem
> - A software algorithm
> - Software tools commonly used by programmers
> - A practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
> - Not about general computing hardware and software **unless directly involving tools used primarily for programming**.
> - [Do we need [texas-instruments]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287618/do-we-need-texas-instruments)

Comment: As the RC remit says, "How to use or preserve computing equipment that is no longer manufactured or supported by the manufacturer." The TI-84 Plus is relatively recent (released 2004) and is still a current model in the TI linup, being manufactured and sold for use today. So this does not seem to be a "retrocomputing" question. (Old calculators that are no longer made or supported would be on topic, though.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to [Cemetech](https://www.cemetech.net/forum/).  I programmed the TI-84 plus calculator off and on for 8 years (I did some serious programming projects in it for my intro to cryptography course, wrote a partial 4x4x4 Rubik's cube solver, many math applications, etc.), and many of the members on there made me look like a newbie.  They have more information on there than most would like to know exists about those calculators!